# How can you apply sequence-wise batch normalization after each layer in a multi-layer RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, batch-normalization

I am reproducing the Sequential MNIST experiment from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04831), where they use a Recurrent Neural Network with 6 layers and apply batch normalization **after** each layer.

They seem to use sequence-wise normalization meaning that the outputs are normalized not only across batches but across time steps as well. This is a problem, because it means that I cannot modify the `BasicRNNCell` to do the batch normalization in the cell's `call` method. For that to work the method would have to know what it outputs in the future time steps.

So, my current solution is for each layer to:

1. Unroll the RNN layer
2. Add a batch normalization layer after this

In code it looks like this:

```py
layer_input = network_input
for layer in range(6):
  cell = BasicRNNCell(128)
  layer_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, layer_input)

  layer_output = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer_output)
  layer_input = layer_output
network_output = layer_output
```

**My question**: Unrolling the RNN for every layer seems like the brute force way to achieve sequence-wise batch normalization after each layer. Is there a more efficient way, for example one that uses [`MultiRNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/MultiRNNCell)?

Comment: I do not suppose that unrolling a loop will be inefficient. Check the definition here in the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L1222). They seems to be using the loop as well.

Comment: @layog when using `MultiRNNCell`, I could do `dynamic_rnn(MultiRNNCell)`, which causes only one unrolling. In my code, I unroll each layer. It might result in the same efficiency but I am unsure if unrolling one layer six times is equally efficient to unrolling six layers once.

Thank you for the link to the source - I will try out both ways without batch normalization and compare the resulting graphs / runtimes.

Comment: Yeah, do share the results

Comment: It seems like unrolling one layer six times causes quite the overhead - both in the computational graph and the runtime. I ran some experiments on Sequential MNIST with 6 layers of 128 units each and a batch size of 32. Unrolling six layers once caused a training time of 0.54 seconds / batch. Unrolling one layer six times caused a training time of 1.54 seconds / batch.